# File ecnryption using DES decrypting garbage - C#

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, des

I am trying to write a simple file encrypter in C# using `DESCryptoServiceProvider`. The file format I am encrypting is `.jpg`. The encryption appears to look fine, but when I decrypt the encrypted file I get an error message in Windows Photo Viewer.

Here is my code:

```
public static void Encrypt(string inputFileName, string outputFileName, string key)
    {
        var inputPath = path + "\\" + inputFileName;
        var outputPath = path + "\\" + outputFileName; 

        try
        {
            FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(inputPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            FileStream fsEncrypted = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

            DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
            DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
            DES.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

            ICryptoTransform desencrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();
            CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, desencrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            byte[] bytearrayinput = new byte[fsInput.Length - 1];
            fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
            cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("file encrypted @ {0}", outputFileName);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("catch in encryption: " + ex.Message + "\n\nclosing...");
        }
    }

    public static void Decrypt(string inputFileName, string outputFileName, string key)
    {
        var inputPath = path + "\\" + inputFileName;
        var outputFileHoler = inputFileName.Substring(0, (outputFileName.IndexOf('.') + 4)); //FIX TO REMOVE REGEX
        var outputPath = path + "\\" + outputFileHoler;

        Console.WriteLine(outputPath); //TEMP

        try
        {
            DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
            DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
            DES.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

            FileStream fsread = new FileStream(inputPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            ICryptoTransform desdecrypt = DES.CreateDecryptor();
            CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(fsread, desdecrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            StreamWriter fsDecrypted = new StreamWriter(outputPath);

            fsDecrypted.Write(new StreamReader(cryptostream).ReadToEnd());
            fsDecrypted.Flush();
            fsDecrypted.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("file decrypted @ {0}", outputPath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("catch in decryption: " + ex.Message + "\n\nclosing...");
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS. completely new to cryptography, please forgive me if it is something simple...

Comment: 1) You don't close the streams during encryption 2) You don't check the return value of `Read`. It may read less data than what you request. 3) padding=none will crash if the file length isn't a multiple of 8 bytes. Use PKCS7 instead. 4) Don't use `StreamReader`. It's designed for text, not binary data.

Comment: 5) DES is very weak 6) Don't use an ASCII string as key 7) don't use a constant as IV 8) Add a MAC

Comment: whoa...thanks. I know (in theory) DES is weak...just doing this for my own edu really. Thanks for the info, will fix up what you mentioned.

Comment: Even if you don't care that DES can be brute forced in 20 hours, there's no reason to use it. AES is faster, more widely supported, and much more secure.

Answer (score 1):

**Do NOT attempt to implement crypto yourself** unless you are 100% sure that you know what you are doing. Use well-reviewed, high-level(!) libraries.

You are attempting to use DES. DES is broken and insecure due to insufficient key length. Do not use it.

You are using your key instead of a random value as IV. Depending on how the crypto provider works, this either introduces a small vulnerability or makes your encryption 100% worthless because it leaks your key.

You are not using any padding. This will make it impossible to correctly encrypt/decrypt files that do not exactly fit the block size.

You do not show how you obtain your key. Chances are you do so in an insecure manner. Especially given that you use a string to store it.

The comments by CodesInChaos have pointed out quite a few important points. What is breaking your files is probably the StreamReader, the padding, and the lack of stream flushing/closing. However, again, **do NOT attempt to write crypto code** - it **will** be insecure even if you get it working.

Comment: This whole thing is just for my education. I understand DES is weak, just trying to get some 'hands on' implementation experience at the code level as opposed to writing notes in my my info-sec text books. The code is not going to be used as a service or released to a production environment.

Comment: OK, then I'd suggest to use something more common (AES), and encrypt simple text files first (e.g. 16 bytes of the letter a). Encrypt the file using OpenSSL (you can give key, IV and cipher mode there), encrypt it yourself, compare the outputs. If they don't match, attempt to decrypt the file, and see if you can find any pattern (e.g. first block ok, second broken). *Then* move to binary files. Also, it would probably be a good idea to read up on block cipher modes, the meaning of the IV, etc. first. It *will* help you understand and implement correctly. And spot some crappy implementations...